# Styling Dynamically Added Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, styles

So I've looked online in this issue, but can't seem to find the answer. Let me explain my problem fully.

I'm trying to dynamically add content to an `<ul>` and have it all formatted correctly. What I'm inserting to is this:

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="localStoresUL" data-autodividers="true" data-divider-theme="d">
</ul>
```

I have a list item somewhere else that is clicked and loads this up with data, and I am doing that with the following code:

```
$("#localStores").click(function() {
     Customer.getLocalStores(13, 12, function(stores){ 
        for(var i = 0; i < stores.length; i++){
           $("#localStoresUL").append('<li class="store" id="' + stores[i].id + '"><a data-transition="slide" data-filter="false">' + stores[i].fullname + '</a></li>'); 
        } 
     }); 
});
```

Now this works all fine and dandy the first time the user clicks the link and it populates that `<ul>`. But I have a back button on the page using this code:

```
<a href="#" class="ui-btn-left back" data-rel="back" data-icon="back"  data-add-back-btn="true" >Back</a>
```

And when the user clicks this back button and then clicks on the previous `<li>` again (which should populate the `<ul>`) the content is loaded dynamically, but not formatted at all. I have no idea why this is happening. Does this problem make sense, and does anybody have any tips for how to fix it?

Comment: "Does this problem make sense" No, not really. I which browser do you face that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it does. It shouldn't.

You need to call `.refresh()` on the listview.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if content is loaded but not formatted, you have an issue with your CSS. Inspect the loaded elements with firebug and see what classes are present and style rules are being applied. Then double check that your relevant CSS selectors match those elements.